# Dropdown in Grafana dynamically populate with values pulled from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I want to add a dynamic drop down menu in Grafana that populates the drop down list with the list of tests that are pulled from BigQuery.

There will be hundreds of tests pulled from BigQuery and I don't want the panel to become too cluttered with tests at the bottom so I want to have a drop down that dynamically populates with all the test names pulled from BigQuery.

The image below shows just a small sample but this will grow to be much larger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [Grafana variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/).

Go to the dashboard `Settings` -> `Variables` and create a new variable with the type set to `Query`. Select your BigQuery data source as Data Source. Then you can write a SQL query that returns one column with all your test names. Save the variable.

Then there should be a dropdown at the top of the dashboard where you can choose the test name you want from. Then use the variable in your query, for example in the WHERE clause to filter for those test names only.